# bdutil: How to launch a Hadoop cluster with a requested image id? (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

When I attempt to launch a Hadoop cluster with the bdutil command, using one of the following:

```
bdutil -b a_hadoop_test -n 1 -P mycluster -e hadoop2_env.sh -i ubuntu-1204 deploy
```

OR

```
bdutil -b a_hadoop_test -n 1 -P mycluster -e hadoop2_env.sh -i ubuntu-1204-precise-v20150316 deploy
```

I receive the following error:

```
******************* gcloud compute stderr *******************
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch image resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my_project_name/global/images/ubuntu-1204' was not found
```

What do I need to do to launch with a requested Ubuntu image?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's the answer - I messed up the instance name. It's actually:

```
ubuntu-12-04
```

...so the command is:

```
bdutil -b a_hadoop_test -n 1 -P mycluster -e hadoop2_env.sh -i ubuntu-12-04 deploy
```